# Excel MIN() if adjacent cell matches previous row's value

Tags: excel-formula, min

I am trying to design an Excel formula that, based on an adjacent column's value compared to the previous row's value returns the minimum of the column.
Here is a specific example:

[image]

Given this data, the value **800** should be returned, because only **1800, 9000, and 800** should be considered, because those are the first cells where the *Track* column changes.

I have tried a variety of combinations with MIN() MINIFS(), MIN()/IF(), INDRIECT()/ADDRESS()/ROW()... but could not come up with a working example.

In pseudocode:

```
min_value = 999999
FOR EACH cell in A3 to A9

  IF value(adjacent cell in C) IS NOT value(adjacent cell in C - 1) THEN
    IF cell < min_value THEN
      set min_value to value(cell)
    END IF
  END IF

END FOR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution will based on Array Formulas.

Enter the following formula:
`=MIN(IF(C2:C8<>C1:C7,A2:A8,"NULL"))`

Then press Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

The formula will compare each cell in range `C2:C8` to the cell above.
When `TRUE` the min function will consider the corresponding cell in `A2:A8` range otherwise `NULL` will be consider (that is some dummy string value that the min function will ignore)

Comment: Thank you, your example works well. I only adjusted it to ignore empty cells. I didn't know they are only interpreted as array formulas if you Ctrl+Shift+Enter them. How subtle.